# MongoDB - Compound group

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have cities collection of documents, where my document is as follow:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fe1d364b5ab856eea75ebc"),
    "elevation" : 1855,
    "name" : "Kud",
    "country" : "India",
    "lon" : 75.28,
    "lat" : 33.08,
    "isPartOf" : [
        "Jammu and Kashmir",
        "Udhampur district"
    ],
    "timeZone" : [
        "Indian Standard Time"
    ],
    "population" : 1140
}
```

I am interested to find the "the average regional city population for all countries in the cities collection".  My aggregation pipeline command is as follow:

```
pipeline = [
            {"$match": {"isPartOf":{"$exists":1}, "country":{"$exists":1}}},
            {"$unwind": "$isPartOf"},
            {"$group":{"_id": {"isPartOf": "$isPartOf", "country": "$country"}, "avgRegionalPopulation": {"$avg":"$population"}}},
            {"$sort": {"avgRegionalPopulation":-1}}
            ]
```

But it seems I am missing something. Since 'avgRegionalPopulation' for 'Lithuania' should be 14750.784447977203. What do I missing in my pipeline command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed the average population for each country step.  This is a correct aggregate pipeline command:

```
pipeline = [
            {"$match": {"isPartOf":{"$exists":1}, "country":{"$exists":1}}},
            {"$unwind": "$isPartOf"},
            {"$group" : {"_id": {"isPartOf": "$isPartOf", "country": "$country"}, "avgregion":{"$avg":"$population"}}},
            {"$group": {"_id": "$_id.country", "avgRegionalPopulation": {"$avg":"$avgregion"}}},
            {"$sort": {"country":-1}}
            ]
```